# How to take TimeInput only in React-Admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

This code from [React-Admin docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DateTimeInput.html) allows me to input Date and Time:

```
import { DateTimeInput } from 'react-admin';

<DateTimeInput source="published_at" />
```

Is there a way to input ONLY time in React-Admin?

Answer (score 0):

https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/time-picker/

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker';

export default function BasicTimePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <TimePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get the following error after trying the above code:
`Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/date-fns/is_valid/index.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/eshaangupta/Desktop/prototype/node_modules/date-fns/is_valid/index.js'`